# Misplaced \omit in table and {} at the end of a command

Tags: tables, macros

The following LaTeX document does not compile.

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{ltablex}
\usepackage[]{multirow}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\noindent{}
\begin{tabularx}{\linewidth}{Xl}
  \bottomrule{}%
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{TESTING}\\*\midrule{}%
  \textbf{Left} & \textbf{Right}\\*\toprule{}%
  \endfirsthead{}%
  %
  \toprule{}%
  \multicolumn{2}{c}{\emph{continuing}}\\*\midrule{}%
  \textbf{Left} & \textbf{Right}\\*\bottomrule{}%
  \endhead{}%
  %
  \lipsum[1][1-2] & first  \\\midrule{}%
  \lipsum[2][1-2] & second \\\midrule{}%
  \lipsum[3][1-2] & third  \\\midrule{}%
  \lipsum[4][1-2] & third  \\\bottomrule{}%
\end{tabularx}

\end{document}
```

pdflatex is giving the error message:

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.26 \end{tabularx}
```

I have observed that if `{}%` is removed from the source, it compiles.

What is the explanation for this behaviour?

The real document I am working with is generated by a Haskell program using the [HaTeX](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/HaTeX) library, which uses to append `{}` to commands with no arguments.

Comment: `\omit` must be the first token in a cell (probably after some expansions). Since `{}` is not expandable, `\omit` is no longer the first token in that cell, hence the error about a misplaced `\omit`. `\multicolumn` expands to something with `\multispan` as its first token and `\multispan` expands to `\omit\@multispan`, so after two steps of expansion, `\multicolumn` is turned into something with `\omit` as the first token.

Comment: Well, the Haskell program does wrong. The culprits are *precisely* those wrong `{}` tokens.

Comment: Argumentless commands *that produce text* are in most occasions best followed by `{}`. Those that don't produce text *should not* have `{}` after them, but a simple space.

Comment: Is it safe to put a space after any command without arguments in general? I remember reading somewhere that spaces after commands are discarded. Is that right?

Comment: In almost all cases, spaces are removed after all command names, i.e. control sequences that are built of a backslash followed by letters. Note that control characters like \\, \> etc. don't discard the following space(s).

Comment: @Romildo Yes, it's safe for commands whose name consists of letters. The only problem is if the command generates text. But it's quite rare and you Haskell program should not take that case as the general one. Commands to be protected that way can be added as exceptions.

Answer (score 4):

The `{}` after `\noindent` does not generate a TeX error, but the newline after it forces bad output, as the paragraph has been started prematurely the newline generates a non-discarded space at the start of the paragraph, which looks a bit like indentation but is not indented by a fixed `\parindent` it is a word space.

Compare the two paragraphs:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\noindent
AAA

\noindent{}
AAA
\end{document}
```

---

`\multicolumn` must be first the command (after expansion) in its cell, any non expandable tokens will cause `\multicolumn` to generate an error, as it is too late to change the cell template.

So the example could be simplified to

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}


\begin{tabular}{c}
a\\
{}\multicolumn{1}{l}{x}  
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

which generates

```
! Misplaced \omit.
\multispan ->\omit 
                   \@multispan 
l.8 {}\multicolumn{1}{l}{x}
```